# Localization issue with French language

Tags: objective-c, localization, return-value

at the moment I´m doing some testing with my first localized application. See Screenshot.
In order to use localized text in a PopUpMenu on first use I´m using this to find out what system I´m on:

```
NSString *identifier = [[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier];
```

On a German system identifier returns **de_DE**, On an English system I get **en_EN_POSIX**.
On a French system I would expect to get **fr_FR** but unfortunately I also get **de_DE**.

Any idea what I´m doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Did you change your region or your language?  I've you've changed your devices language setting but not your devices region then I can see why your locale would still give you your response for germany.

Comment: That was the problem, Thanks a lot. In fact I have 3 accounts on my mac. For each language one. Although I sat up the French account from the beginning as French for some reason region was German.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that this locale is set in the system preferences. Select language&text, then the region text and switch it to your region.

[image]